# PFUser.current() always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

In the `viewDidLoad()` of the Initial View Controller in my app I run this:

```
let currentUser = PFUser.current()

        if currentUser != nil{

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTabs", sender: self)
    }
```

`currentUser` is always nil.

I run `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()` in the AppDelegate.Swift after I configure the parse client as per the latest parse server Ios SDK. This should make it so that when ever a user is logged in they stay logged in unless a logout command is run. I have no idea why this isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging, I realized that `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()` was functioning normally. The problem was that the `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTabs", sender: self)` wasn't dispatched to the main queue. I fixed this by changing my code to:

```
 let currentUser = PFUser.current()

    if currentUser?.username != nil{

        print(currentUser!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async(){

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTabs", sender: self)

        }

    }else{

        print("No current User")
  }
```

Thanks, to all of you for your help, and I'm sorry to have wasted your time with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running Parse version 2.2 (or older, not sure), where did you call the `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()`?, I solved it by calling it right after the ApplicationID was made:

```
Parse.setApplicationId(parseApplicationID, clientKey:parseClientKey)
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

I enable keychain sharing, clean, delete the app, and reinstall to get things to work properly.

Here are [steps to enable keychain.](http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/)